# CSS not getting applied in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styling

I am trying to display my progress bar using flex so that I can have a tag before the progress bar but it is not getting applied. I am not sure as to why it is not happening.

Please suggest.

[image: Screenshot]

**About.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./About.css";
import { ProgressBar } from "react-bootstrap";

function About() {
  return (
    <div className="MainAboutContainer">
      <div classNames="Skills">
        <h3 className="SkillTag">hi</h3>
        <div className="SkillLevel">
          <ProgressBar now={60} label={`${60}%`} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default About;
```

**About.css**

```
.Skills {
  display: "flex";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the 's' in `ClassNames="Skills"` to make `ClassName="Skills"`